# About the possibility to change the decimal accuracy of weights in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow2.x

There is a problem that I need to change the decimal accuracy of layer weights in Keras.
Any solution for that? I have known that there is a method to change the format of weights between float16/32/64, but I really want to do is limiting the weight at specific digit, for example,

One number of weights: change 1.0454446 to 1.0454000 like the function floor()

Are there some module functions for that operation? Or anyway directly I could change the module?

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is a process called "quantization".

One of the most used techniques is called post-training quantization, process during which you convert the weights (even activations provided several criteria are met) to float16 or even int8.

You can read about quantisation and its subparts in this link : https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization